# Excluding particular columns from being resampled using pandas resample

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

The following is a simplification of the problem at hand.

I have a dataframe containing three columns, the date a state began, the state itself, and a flag field. It looks similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'begin': pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-05', '2018-07-11', '2018-11-14', '2019-02-19']),
    'state': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'started': [1, 0, 0, 0]
     }
)

df

       begin  state  started
0 2018-01-05      1        1
1 2018-07-11      2        0
2 2018-11-14      3        0
3 2019-02-19      4        0
```

I want to resample the dates so that they have a monthly period, and I achieve this as follows:

```
df.set_index('begin', drop=False).resample('m').ffill()

df 
                begin  state  started
begin                                
2018-01-31 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-02-28 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-03-31 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-04-30 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-05-31 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-06-30 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-07-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-08-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-09-30 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-10-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-11-30 2018-11-14      3        0
2018-12-31 2018-11-14      3        0
2019-01-31 2018-11-14      3        0
2019-02-28 2019-02-19      4        0
```

Everything looks ok, except for the flag column (`started`). I need it to be 1 exactly once, at its first occurrence as in the original dataframe.

The **desired** output is :

```
                begin  state  started
begin                                
2018-01-31 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-02-28 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-03-31 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-04-30 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-05-31 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-06-30 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-07-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-08-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-09-30 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-10-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-11-30 2018-11-14      3        0
2018-12-31 2018-11-14      3        0
2019-01-31 2018-11-14      3        0
2019-02-28 2019-02-19      4        0
```

Thus, for a given combination of `begin` and `state`, if `started` is 1, it should be one only at the first occurrence of this combination.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only `1` and `0` in `started` column use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with specify both columns in list:

```
mask = df.duplicated(['begin','started'])
```

Also is possible rewrite only `1` values by chain another mask:

```
mask = df.duplicated(['begin','started']) & df['started'].eq(1)
```

---

```
df.loc[mask, 'started'] = 0
```

Or:

```
df['started'] = np.where(mask, 0, df['started'])

print (df)
                begin  state  started
begin                                
2018-01-31 2018-01-05      1        1
2018-02-28 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-03-31 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-04-30 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-05-31 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-06-30 2018-01-05      1        0
2018-07-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-08-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-09-30 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-10-31 2018-07-11      2        0
2018-11-30 2018-11-14      3        0
2018-12-31 2018-11-14      3        0
2019-01-31 2018-11-14      3        0
2019-02-28 2019-02-19      4        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do:

```
df = df.set_index('begin', drop=False).resample('m').ffill()
df.loc[df['started'].duplicated(keep='first'), 'started'] = 0
```